# How for a plurality of interface stress test

Tags: loadrunner

i use LoadRunner.
now we have some Interface , i want to record script for stress test
if record one by one is so waste time .

can i record or write one script complete all ?

Comment: I think the question is not clear. Can you explain what you want in more detail please?

Answer (score 2):

You can create one script or several. E.g. one script with 20 transactions might be hard for you or another tester to understand and update. Scripts with 3 - 5 transactions are easier to read and update.

Also in some cases, complex logic of the application under testing (AUT) might not allow you create one test script.

Another reason for not recording one big script is that if recording fails for some reason, you might lose all the recorded transactions at once, and this will be a waste of time too.